# Multiple pages in one html document

Tags: css, html

So I have five different coded pages. What I want to do is combine them all into one html page. I have my home page with a navigation bar that links to the other pages but whenever I try to insert my other pages, the multiple pages overlay one another or appear in a column underneath. What sort of code do I need so the clickable links pull up my other pages without it overlaying. Below is a section of my code that I want linked to another page.

```css
    }

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.image1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 290px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: 400px;
  background-position: 10px 280px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index: -3.0;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  height: 290px;
  width: 400px;
}

.container:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 330px;
  height: 240px;
  overflow: scroll;
  top: 15%;
  left: 48%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display:block;
  width:150px;
  height: 70px;
  border:2px solid #C5E3ED;
  color:#ADD7C9;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a { text-decoration: none; color:#C5E3ED }
a:visited { text-decoration: none; color:#C5E3ED; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; color:#C5E3ED; }
a:focus { text-decoration: none; color:#C5E3ED; }
a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: none; color:#C5E3ED }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/3779/large/how-to-care-for-a-dog-with-a-stomach-upset-58345cd2daf98.jpg" alt="dog" class="image1">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">
    <a href="http://google.com">About</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need to see your html/css code to help you out. Please post it as a snippet. The answer might require javascript/jquery.

Comment: Did I add the right section of my code?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this guide to create a collapsible frame for you. 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp

You can add your html code in div with class="content". Let me know if it is what you wanted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    /* Style the button that is used to open and close the collapsible content */
    .collapsible {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    }

    /* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
    .active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */
    .content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
    <div class="content">
    !--- YOUR HTML CODE HERE ---!
</div>
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorta, I edited my post with some code. Does my question make more sense?